# can somebody help about beautiifulsoup4 installationi

Tags: python

ı am trying to install beautifulsoup4, actually its kinda installed with "pip" module but ı cant access to module from the shell, whenever ı go to python files whether it is installed, ı have only a file named "beautifulsoup4-4.4.1.dist-info" but ı have no actual beautifulsoup4 file. when ı uninstall and try to install again encountering such a screen in the shell , what can ı do?

Collecting beautifulsoup4
  Using cached beautifulsoup4-4.4.1-py3-none-any.whl
  Saved c:\users\gurhan\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\beautifulsoup4-4.4.1-py3-none-any.whl
Successfully downloaded beautifulsoup4
0

Comment: Did you try importing it? `pip` usually installs packages to your system.

Comment: You need to write a script. Then you just import it into your module. For example: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`. You might want to look at the [Quick Start](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start) and maybe find a basic tutorial on using Python modules.

Comment: the package is named `bs4` - you `import bs4`.

Comment: thanks for answering but ı ve tried this part also. but shell doesnt importing beautifulsoup from bs4 when ı go to directory of bs4, actually there is not any file named beautifulsoup 4 for or any other ı also tried, working with only bs4, so try to execute beatifulsoup attributes for bs4, as you can guess i doesnt work either.

Comment: its from the shell////////////////////   from bs4 import beautifulSoup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import beautifulSoup
ImportError: cannot import name 'beautifulSoup'

Comment: somehow, my beautifulsoup4 doesn't installed in my python/lib/site_packages directory, only installed thing about beautifulsoup4 is "dist-info" which isntknown by me what it is exactly.

Answer (score 0):

The importable package name for project `BeautifulSoup4` is somewhat unintuitively named `bs4`; thus in your code you need to `import bs4`; and you'd expect to find a directory named `bs4`.

---

In [PEP 0423](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0423/#use-a-single-name) (deferred) it was proposed as a guideline that the project name in `PyPI` be the package name, so that if you `import bs4`, you'd also `pip install bs4`; however BeautifulSoup 4 does not follow this recommendation.